# Find a function $f :\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$ which is not differentiable at $(0,0)$ even though all directional derivatives of $f$ exist at $(0,0).$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, examples-counterexamples

This is a practice exam question and I have no idea how to start it.

> Find a function $f :\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$ which is not differentiable at $(0,0)$ even though all directional derivatives of $f$ exist at $(0,0).$

Comment: The usual suspect seems to be of the form $\frac{x^ay^b}{x^c+y^c}$.

Comment: That guy must be tired of always being suspected. ;-)

Comment: @martycohen how did you come to this conclusion?

Comment: Choose a different slope for each direction, and make $f$ linear along that line.

Comment: Problems that I've seen in the past.